# Synchronize the user from ldap server to jira soon

Tags: ldap, jira, confluence, synchronize

I was using a openldap server to control the user in jira and confluence. But after I insert a user into ldap and add the user into the jira-users group, i still need to synchronize the user in jira. Can i set something to let it synchronize automatically after i insert the user into ldap server?

Answer (score 0):

Here are the main steps :

- Log in as a user with the *JIRA System Administrators* permission
- Check your configuration : `Settings > User Management > User Directories`
- You can manually synchronize the LDAP cache by clicking 'Synchronize' on the 'User Directories' screen.

If it works, you just need to set the *Synchronization Interval* on the directory configuration screen.

Otherwise there is probably something wrong with the current config. In this case, I would:

- Check the server settings, see if it's reachable when connecting from a terminal.
- Similarly, try to perform a search from a terminal using the schema settings.
- Disable *Incremental Synchronization* if enabled.
- Ensure the directory order is correct. Changes to users and groups will be made *only* in the first directory where the application has permission to make changes.

Ref: [Connecting to an LDAP directory](https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver071/connecting-to-an-ldap-directory-802592350.html)